# Converting objective C alloc init to swift with required argument

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working on a Swift metawear (mbientlab.com) project and all the code examples are in Objective C so have to do lots of conversion.  Following this blog post - http://projects.mbientlab.com/persistent-events-and-filters/ - I created the following class that inherits from MBLRestorable (which implements the NSCoder protocol):

```
class DeviceConfiguration:NSObject, MBLRestorable {
var pulseWithEvent:MBLEvent!

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.pulseWithEvent, forKey: "pulseWithEvent")
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

    self.pulseWithEvent = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pulseWithEvent") as MBLEvent
}
}
```

So far so good. Now I am converting the following Objective C to Swift:

```
[self.device setConfiguration:[[DeviceConfiguration alloc] init] handler:^(NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
// Programming successful!
}
}];
```

I try:

```
self.device.setConfiguration(MetawearConfig()) { error in
```

}

But get an error that it is missing the required argument "coder."  Make sense to me that it would require that param on init but in the Objective C sample code/applications a coder obj is never passed in (and the compiler does not raise the same error).

The declaration for setConfiguration is:

```
- (void)setConfiguration:(id<MBLRestorable>)configuration handler:(MBLErrorHandler)handler;
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Can you please show the signature for `self.device.setConfiguration`

Comment: I just added the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift classes do not by default inherit the superclass's initializers (See Swift language guide -> Initialization -> search for section "Automatic Initializer Inheritance"). `NSObject`'s `init()` is a "designated initializer". Designated initializers are only inherited by a subclass if the subclass implements *no* designated initializers of its own. Since your `DeviceConfiguration` class implements a designated initializer `init(coder:)`, it does not inherit designated initializers from its superclass. That's why `DeviceConfiguration` does not have an initializer with signature `init()`.

Objective-C is different in that initializers are just methods in Objective-C and are always inherited.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `MetawearConfig()`, but the only `init` you provide is `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. If you want a non-parameter `init`, you must provide one:

```
init() {
    // initialize your object
}
```

Comment: But the Objective-C version that you can see at http://projects.mbientlab.com/persistent-events-and-filters/ does not provide one.

Comment: Swift and ObjC are different languages and have different rules for object initialization. Note that generally speaking, basic language translation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging

Answer (score 0):

The `DeviceConfiguration` in Objective-C would also have a different `init` with no parameters, inherited from `NSObject`.  The code you're converting looks to be calling the no-parameter version rather than the `NSCoder` version.

Comment: Are you saying that in Objective-C it would inherit a non-parameter init method that it wouldn't in Swift?